# Milliseconds to datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this statement

```
EXEC [spProject_Update] @ProjectID = 496
,@Name = 'Hangman Bollywood iPhone'
,@Description = ''
,@EstimateTime = 2674800000
```

I will get milliseconds in `@EstimateTime`.
How can I convert this to `datetime` in SQL Server?

Comment: What do the miliseconds relate to? Number of ms after current time?

Comment: @MartinSmith no after default value of datetime

Comment: Doesn't make any sense. There is no default value of datetime. If you are referring to `1 Jan 1900` then `2674800000` milliseconds is only `743` hours so doesn't seem likely.

Comment: @MartinSmith '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' for this if we add 743 hours It should add 30 days(743/24) + remaining in time cant make sense???? Is there any way to do this like using DATEADD function?

Comment: So you are using 1 Jan 1900 as a reference date? Why? `DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 2674800000,0)` fails with an overflow error. `DATEADD(SECOND, 2674800,0)` works but I presume that you aren't actually going to be using dates in 1900 so that will overflow too. Why not just pass in as `datetime`?

Comment: @MartinSmith We get estmate time in hours like 700, 900 etc. we convert that into millisecond and sending it to db and have to store it as datetime.

Comment: And why not just store the number of hours as an `int` rather than a nonsensical `datetime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATETIME` is used to store an instant ("point in time") at a particular granularity (approx 300 milliseconds IIRC).

The value you wish to store is an interval (or is it a duration?) in milliseconds. SQL Server lacks an interval data type.

While both are temporal data they have quite different requirements. I suggest you use an numeric column (e.g. `INTEGER`) to store the interval and use metadata (e.g. an appropriate name) to convey the fact the granularity is one millisecond.